# php json_encode for php < 5.4 (unexpected token)

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a jquery ajax which invokes a php file which outputs a json object.

It all works great on versions of php higher than 5.3, but lower versions don't have `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, and JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` implemented yet.

How do I escape "json sensitive" chars like "&" or "=" in earlier versions?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:
scratch that.. the problem is =>
i have `<br />` in the text and that gets changed to `<br \="">`
the `"` gives the error...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `&` and `=` are treated as normal characters in JSON, you're probably thinking of URLs.

Comment: no, i get the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =" error when parsing.. same goes for "&"

Comment: @Andrej Example, please.

Comment: @Gumbo example of the string i'm trying to parse? it's really long, i can maybe put a part of it here.. but I don't get those errors locally when using json_encode with said bitmask constants..

Comment: @Andrej An example where this error occurs.

Comment: What's the problem?  `'{"I\'m testing:": "http://google.com?q=a&b=c"}'` is valid JSON.

Comment: here's a sample `{[url={http:\/\/motercalo.pointslash.info|http:\/\/motercalo.wordpress.com}]{motercalo|moter calo}[\/url][\/tag], j'ai d\u00c3\u00a9cid\u00c3\u00a9 de vous en}` and this gives me`SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: @Andrej: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: that's what I get with json_encode

Comment: @All of course, this is just a part of the message I get.. as i said it's very long... let's say this is the short version `{"error":"","title":"{Hello|Bonjour|Salut} {je s}"}`

Comment: @Andrej That’s what you get from `json_encode` with what input? And what do you do with its output?

Comment: @Andrej: Are you sure?  What was the original array you tried to `json_encode`?

Comment: @Andrej: That "short version" works fine.

Comment: @Gumbo the input is content from a .txt file, so it's big... the output basically that .txt file split into smaller chucks and put in an array which is as a parameter given to json_encode

Comment: @Gumbo yes, this does.. but later in the "title" string I have a bunch of "&" and "=" chars.. which break it

Comment: `{"error":"","title":"{Hello|Bonjour|Salut} {je s} {test&stuff=123}"}` works fine.

Comment: @Rocket: You cannot escape `'` in JSON. That's parse error according to the specification.

Comment: @GlitchMr: Huh?  What are you talking about?  `JSON.parse('{"I\'m testing:": "http://google.com?q=a&b=c"}')` works fine.

Comment: @Andrej Again, give us an example that reproduces this error.

Comment: @Gumbo sorry i edited the post, I was wrong.. here's what happens => <br /> gets changed to <br \=""> and the extra double quotes break the string

Comment: @Andrej `json_decode(json_encode('<br />')) === '<br />'` — So what *exactly* are you doing?

Comment: @Gumbo here's the link to the file [link](http://restaurantguide-croatia.com/aspinner.txt).. the <br /> in this file breaks the string

Comment: @Andrej Please show us the exact code. We can’t help you unless we know exactly what you’re doing with the mentioned text file.

Comment: @Andrej: What are you doing with that text file?  It's not JSON, it's just a text file.

Comment: @All heres what I added to the code (and it helped) `str_replace("<", "\u003C", $string)` and `str_replace(">", "\u003E", $string)`

Comment: Let's stop with the interactive debugging session.  The comments are not the place to do this, and it's an indicator that this question is not a real question.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that text file: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2BN7rA

Comment: @Rocket: Read the specification at http://json.org/. `'` is not on list of characters allowed to escape.

Comment: @GlitchMr: It was only escaped because the entire string was quoted in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UTF-8 Encoding, you can use this:

```
$json = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $json);
```

For JSON_UNESCAPED_SLAHES, you can use:

```
preg_replace('\\/', '/', $json);
```

JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE might be a bit more complicated, I found some examples on php.net manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).